# Shapeless zipWithKeys: Could not find implicit parameter

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I've been playing around with shapeless recently. There is this very basic thing I can't wrap my head around:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.singleton._
import record._

object NotWorking {
  val result = ("value" :: HNil).zipWithKeys("key" :: HNil)
}
```

I expect this snippet to output an extensible Record. But the compiler is not able to find an implicit for `withKeys`:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter withKeys: shapeless.ops.hlist.ZipWithKeys[shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil],shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]
[error]     ("value" :: HNil).zipWithKeys("key" :: HNil)
```

It's even more confusing, as the example I took form Shapeless' test cases works perfectly:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.singleton._
import record._

object ShamelesslyStolenFromTests {
  val orig =
    ("intField" ->> 1) ::
    ("boolField" ->> true) ::
    HNil

  val result = orig.values.zipWithKeys(orig.keys)
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are your imports?

Comment: Hi @GáborBakos, see updated question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code compiles:

```
  import shapeless._
  import syntax.singleton._
  import record._

  object FinallyWorking {
    val result = ("value" :: HNil).zipWithKeys[Witness.`"key"`.T :: HNil]("key".narrow :: HNil)
  }
```

So it seems this was an issue with type inference for type parameter of the method.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Do you know whether `zipWithKeys` is really intended to be used like that? I feel like there must be a more straight-forward approach. Could this be a bug in shapeless?

Comment: This is definitely not a bug in shapeless. This is limitation of algorithms for type inference used by compiler. You can use overloaded version of `zipWithKeys`: ``("value" :: HNil).zipWithKeys[Witness.`"key"`.T :: HNil]``. This allows to avoid some code duplication. This `zipWithKeys` works on type level instead of the first `zipWithKeys` working on both type and value level.

Comment: It starts to make sense. Thx! `val result = ("value" :: HNil).zipWithKeys[HList.\`"key"\`.T]` is even a bit more concise.